# How to update object array within another object array with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord, discord.js

I have a problem regarding MongoDB, Mongoose, and Node.js.

I have this schema using Mongoose:

```
const EmoteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    guild_id: String,
    users: [{
        user_id: String,
        emotes: [{
            emote: String,
            channels: [String],
            cooldown: Number,
            all_channels: { type: Boolean, default: true },
            global_cooldown: { type: Boolean, default: true },
            lock: { type: Boolean, default: false }
        }]
    }]
});
```

What it looks like MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6776b9277898982b0a25a"),
    "guild_id" : "714931095929618443",
    "users" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6776b9277898982b0a25b"),
            "user_id" : "160230784257622016",
            "emotes" : [
                {
                    "channels" : [ ],
                    "all_channels" : true,
                    "global_cooldown" : true,
                    "lock" : false,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6776b9277898982b0a25c"),
                    "emote" : ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to update the database, based on three conditions:
When sent the information of the guild_id, user_id, and emote:

1. If the guild_id, user_id, and emote exist in the database do nothing
2. If the guild_id, user_id (and emote does NOT exist), update the emote array with new emote
3. If the guild_id, (and user_id does not exist), update the users array with new user_id and update with the emote
4. If guild_id does not exit: create new entry with new guild_id, users array and emotes array

This is what I have attempted to do:

```
        let filter = {
            guild_id: guild_inp,
            "users.user_id": user_inp
        };
        let update = {
            $push: { "users.$[i].emotes": { emote: emote_inp } } 
        };
        let options = {
            arrayFilters: [
                { "i.users.user_id": user_inp }
            ],
            rawResult: true
        };

        Emote.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, fn);
```

If the guild_inp: 714931095929618443, user_inp: 160230784257622016, and emote: 
The callback functions gets this result:

```
RES: {
  lastErrorObject: { n: 1, updatedExisting: true },
  value: {
    _id: 5ee6776b9277898982b0a25a,
    guild_id: '714931095929618443',
    users: [ [Object] ],
    __v: 0
  },
  ok: 1
}
```

It says that it has been updated? But I see no changes in MongoDB!

Any help is appreciated if there is an easier way to achieve what I am doing such as a new schema please share it!

Comment: For your arrayFilter, try `{ "i.user_id": user_inp }`.  If you specify the array field name there as well, nothing matches so nothing updates.  That update should work if the guild and user exist but the emote doesn't.  What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: @Joe Your update worked like a charm! Now the real question is now, how do I achieve the other 2 requirements (from the list of 4)? I read another StackOverflow post to use the updateOne command multiple times, but that seems inefficient. I also get errors when attempting to use the upsert command...

Comment: I think the only way to get this in one go will be to use the pipeline form of update added in MongoDB 4.2.

Comment: @Joe Do u have a link for documentation of the pipeline that you are referring to?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/index.html#update-command-u